# Prettier how to ignore a single line?

Tags: prettier

How could Prettier ignore a single line of code in an MDX file?

I tried to ignore it like JSX `{/* prettier-ignore */}` or MD `<!-- prettier-ignore -->`file, but it doesn't work for MDX.

Answer (score 2):

The JSX style `{/* prettier-ignore */}` works for me in MDX 2.

Comment: Can you show an example. The following is not working for me:

{/* prettier-ignore */}/r/n
Here is some content which I don't want formatted. Once this line gets too long prettier breaks it into multiple lines.

Comment: This does not actually for my case either. Funnily enough prettier changes it to `{/_ prettier-ignore _/}` which is what I'm trying to prevent